# Can you tell me if this is a calculus problem?

Tags: calculus

I have been asked to solve and I do not know where to start.
$$|(3\pi+0.58)-11|!$$
I have tried several calculators but seem to come up with different answers.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably expected to approximate $3\pi+0.58\approx10$ and solve from there, *i.e.* compute $|10-11|!$. This is not a calculus problem.

(It is possible to take the factorial of a non-whole number using something called the gamma function, which is more like calculus, but you're probably not expected to do that.)

Answer (score 2):

With a pocket calculator one computes $3\pi+0.58-11=-0.99522204$, so that we are told to find $0.99522204!\>$. For integer $n$ one has $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$. This suggests that the Gamma-value $\Gamma(1.99522204)$ is meant, and Mathematica produces
$$\Gamma(1.99522204)=0.997989346\ .$$